# DataTrigger for Image not responding WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datatrigger

I am trying to get my DataTrigger on my image to fire when a boolean is changed in my ViewModel. The code for the image control is:

```
<Image>
                                    <Image.Style>
                                        <Style TargetType="Image">
                                            <Setter Property="Width" Value="15"/>
                                            <Setter Property="Height" Value="15"/>
                                            <Setter Property="Source" Value="{Binding CloseImage}"/>
                                            <Style.Triggers>
                                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TASI}" Value="True">
                                                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="{Binding CheckImage}"/>
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                            </Style.Triggers>
                                        </Style>
                                    </Image.Style>
                                </Image>
```

The ViewModel code is:

```
private bool _TASI;
        public bool TASI
        {
            get { return _TASI; }
            set
            {
                _TASI = value;
                SetPropertyChanged("_TASI");
            }
        }
```

However it seems that when the bool is changed from false to true, the image does not change. The value is changed via an async method:

```
public async void StartUpRoutine()
        {
            await Task.Run(() => PingServer());
            MessageBox.Show("Server Pinged");
        }

public void PingServer()
        {
            if (Directory.Exists(ServerAddress))
            {
                TASI = true;
                MessageBox.Show("Server Found");
            } 
            else
                TASI = false;
        }
```

I know the directory exists because the MessageBox is popping up showing "Server Found". But the DataTrigger isn't firing in my XAML. I can see the CloseImage but not the CheckImage. If I change it to false:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TASI}" Value="False">
```

Then I see the CheckImage and not the CloseImage. So the Image Sources are set right, they just aren't changing when the value is changed in the ViewModel.

Comment: Does it work when you call PingServer() synchronously? That would be very simple to try out.

Comment: Just tested it there now and it does the same thing. No change to the image. I am calling the function PingServer() from the code behind of the MainWindow as I have to instantiate my MainViewModel (called mvm). So calling mvm.PingServer() in the main body of the MainWindow class in code behind.

Comment: You have to call `SetPropertyChanged("TASI");`, i.e. with the property name, not that of the backing field. Or better `SetPropertyChanged(nameof(TASI));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are raising the PropertyChanged event for the wrong property name.

```
SetPropertyChanged("_TASI");
```

needs to be

```
SetPropertyChanged("TASI");
```

or better

```
SetPropertyChanged(nameof(TASI));
```

Comment: `SetPropertyChanged(nameof(TASI))` would be even better.